# Minimize, Maximize and close buttons of Windows title bar does not work on single click when Menu is open

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, popup, contextmenu

While my Menu is open, The first single click on minimize or maximize or close button does not work. The first Click on these title bar buttons closes the Menu and shifts the focus, And then on the second click the minimize/maximize/close of window works.

I referred this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037048/minimize-maximize-and-close-buttons-of-windows-title-bar-does-not-work-on-singl/50047240?noredirect=1#comment87962745_50047240) which states a similar problem for Context menu's and Popups.
But the solution is not working for Menu class.

This is what I tried:

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:TestProject.Controls"
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Menu Style="{StaticResource CustomMenuStyle}" controls:MenuMouseEnhance.Enabled="True">
                            <MenuItem Header="List of Items" >
                                <MenuItem Header="MenuOne" />
                                <MenuItem Header="MenuTwo" />
                            </MenuItem>  
                         </Menu>
```

MenuMouseEnhance.cs

```
  public static class MenuMouseEnhance
    {
        public static bool GetEnabled(UIElement element)
        {
            return (bool)element.GetValue(EnabledProperty);
        }

        public static void SetEnabled(UIElement element, bool value)
        {
            element.SetValue(EnabledProperty, value);
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty EnabledProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "Enabled",
                 typeof(bool),
                 typeof(MenuMouseEnhance),
                 new PropertyMetadata(false, EnabledChanged));



        private static void EnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            MenuItem Menu = d as MenuItem;

            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                Menu.SubmenuOpened += Menu_Opened;
            }
            else
            {
                Menu.SubmenuOpened -= Menu_Opened;
            }
        }



        private static void Menu_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem p = (MenuItem)sender;

            // First, we determine the window we will monitor:
            Window w = Window.GetWindow(p);
            if (w != null)
            {
                // Then, we need a HwndSource instance of that window
                // to be able to insert our custom Message Hook
                HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(w).Handle);
                if (source != null)
                {
                    //Enable the custom window helper!
                    WindowHelper.Enable(source, w, p);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is a custom helper class
        /// This initialized the HwndSource and Window classes through constructor injection
        /// </summary>
        private class WindowHelper
        {
            private readonly HwndSource mHwndSource;
            private readonly Window mWindow;

            /// <summary>
            /// Set the members of this class in constructor
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="hwndSource"></param>
            /// <param name="window"></param>
            private WindowHelper(HwndSource hwndSource, Window window)
            {
                mHwndSource = hwndSource;
                mWindow = window;
            }

        public static void Enable(HwndSource hwndSource, Window window, MenuItem menu)
        {
            WindowHelper helper = new WindowHelper(hwndSource, window);
            hwndSource.AddHook(helper.WndProc);
            menu.SubmenuClosed += helper.Menu_Closed;
        }


        private void Menu_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // The ContextMenu is closed now - disable all!
            MenuItem p = (MenuItem)sender;
            p.SubmenuClosed -= Menu_Closed;
            mHwndSource.RemoveHook(WndProc);
        }


        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            // WM_SETCURSOR will be sent to our window when the user moves the mouse
            // Cursor around and clicks the mouse buttons.
            if (msg != NativeConstants.WM_SETCURSOR)
            {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            // Determine the necessary parameters.    
            //The low-order word of lParam specifies the hit-test code.
            //The high-order word of lParam specifies the identifier of the mouse message.
            var mouseMessage = ((int)lParam & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16;
            var hitTest = (int)lParam & 0xFFFF;

            switch (hitTest)
            {
                // Only continue if the mouse is over
                // The 'minimize', 'maximize', 'close'
                case NativeConstants.HTMINBUTTON:
                case NativeConstants.HTMAXBUTTON:
                case NativeConstants.HTCLOSE:
                    break;

                default:
                    // Otherwise, do nothing.
                    return IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            // If the user clicks outside the Menu,
            // a WM_MOUSEMOVE message will be transmitted via WM_SETCURSOR.
            // So if we've received something other - ignore that.
            if (mouseMessage != NativeConstants.WM_MOUSEMOVE)
            {
                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            // We need to perform these actions manually,
            // because the window will not receive the corresponding messages
            // on first mouse click (when the ContextMenu is still open).
            switch (hitTest)
            {
                case NativeConstants.HTMINBUTTON:
                    mWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                    break;

                case NativeConstants.HTMAXBUTTON:
                    if (mWindow.WindowState.ToString() == "Maximized")
                    {
                        //When Window is maximized
                        //Assign the Normal state to the window when Maximize is pressed
                        mWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //When Window is in normal state
                        //Assign the maximized state to the window when Maximize is pressed
                        mWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                    }
                    break;

                case NativeConstants.HTCLOSE:
                    mWindow.Close();
                    break;
            }

            // We always return 0, because we don't want any side-effects
            // in the message processing.
            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }


    private static class NativeConstants
    {
        public const int WM_SETCURSOR = 0x020;
        public const int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x200;
        public const int HTMINBUTTON = 8;
        public const int HTMAXBUTTON = 9;
        public const int HTCLOSE = 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I proposed the solution in the referenced question, I can easily answer this one.

As I mentioned in the comments there, you should use the `MenuItem.SubMenuOpened` routed event.

So here are the modifications you need to make in order this code to work:

1. Change the `WindowHelper` class to process the `Menu`, not the `MenuItem`s. We're going to set our attached property on a `Menu`, see your XAML!

---

```
private class WindowHelper
{
    // Third parameter is a Menu, not a MenuItem
    public static void Enable(HwndSource hwndSource, Window window, Menu menu)
    {
        WindowHelper helper = new WindowHelper(hwndSource, window);
        hwndSource.AddHook(helper.WndProc);

        // Subscribe to the routed event MenuItem.SubmenuClosed
        menu.AddHandler(MenuItem.SubmenuClosedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)helper.Menu_Closed);
    }

    // The method signature has to be changed - this is a routed event handler now
    private void Menu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu menu = (Menu)sender;
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)e.Source;

        if (menuItem.Parent != menu)
        {
            // If it's not the first level menu, ignore it.
            // We only disable our helper when the whole menu closes.
            return;
        }

        // Unsubscribe from the routed event
        menu.RemoveHandler(MenuItem.SubmenuClosedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)Menu_Closed);
        mHwndSource.RemoveHook(WndProc);
    }

    // Rest is unchanged
    // ...
}
```

2. Change the `Menu_Opened` event handler signature to correspond the `RoutedEventHandler` delegate. Update the event subscription code.

---

```
private static void Menu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    Menu menu = (Menu)sender;
    MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)e.Source;

    if (menuItem.Parent != menu)
    {
        // We don't want to process any sub-menus in the deeper levels,
        // because the helper will already be enabled when
        // a first level menu opens
        return;
    }

    Window w = Window.GetWindow(menu);
    if (w != null)
    {
        HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(w).Handle);
        if (source != null)
        {
            WindowHelper.Enable(source, w, menu);
        }
    }
}
```

3. And finally, update the initial event subscription code - we now have routed events!

---

```
private static void EnabledChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Menu menu = (Menu)d;

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        menu.AddHandler(MenuItem.SubmenuOpenedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)Menu_Opened);
    }
    else
    {
        menu.RemoveHandler(MenuItem.SubmenuOpenedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)Menu_Opened);
    }
}
```

Now this will work for a menu.

By the way, instead of

```
w.WindowState.ToString() == "Maximized"
```

you should use

```
w.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized
```